# Make a container div disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HUGE dynamic form with lots of fields. If one of the parameters is missing I should make all fields disabled (read not clickable). I was wondering if I can instead make the container div disabled using jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Add the code so there could be better understanding

Comment: I cannot add code because the form is 700++ lines long + the jquery is another 400...

Comment: How do you mean make the container div disabled? Disable all inputs within it, or do you mean something else?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Disable all inputs within it

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$('#yourdiv').find(':input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Instead of `:input`, you could use `textarea, button, fieldset, input`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div#optionalid :input').prop('disabled',true);
```

Would apply the `disabled` property and assign it to true on all input fields found within the specified `<div>`. Though your option is vague, I believe this is what you want.

To give more control, you can make this applicable based on the value of that original control:

```
$('#originalInputId').on('change',function(e){
  $('#containerDivId :input').prop('disabled', $(this).val() == '');
});
```

Comment: I have select elements etc etc.. I want to make all fields within the wrapper div disabled

Comment: @Dragan `:input` will get them.

Comment: `:input` is a selector to find `<input>`, `<select>`, `<button>` and other form-input controls.

Comment: @undefined: Yes, it is, because of performance; but it is still a viable option, even as of the latest jQuery.

Comment: worked like a charm. I upvoted everyone's answer but I'm gonna select this as the answer to my question. Thank you Brad that's exactly what I was after

Answer (score 1):

That won't work with a `<div>`, I think, but you can group your inputs using the `<fieldset>` tag and then disable a complete fieldset.

Answer (score 1):

You can make all input contents inside your div disabled using `Jquery` -

```
 if(your condition)
  {
  $('#yourDivId :input').attr('disabled', true);
  }
  else
  {
  $('#yourDivId :input').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
```